# Why is the following matplotlib plot missing a quadrant?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I'm trying to understand matplotlib's polar plot function and have made a very simple dataset to test my understanding.

When I plot the data, only three of the four quadrants show up, and one of the three radial bins are missing.

I've ran the code below with the following results.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = ([1,.5,.25],[1,.5,.25],[1,.5,.25],[1,.5,.25])
r = [0,1,2]
phi = [0, np.pi/2, np.pi, 3*np.pi/2]
rr, phiphi = np.meshgrid(r,phi)


def polar_plot(z):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(projection="polar")
    plt.pcolormesh(phiphi, rr, z, vmin=0, vmax=1)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.plot()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

The plot produced is below:

[image: plot]

As you can see, only two of the three radial bins are plotted, and three of the four angular bins.

Comment: Yes, the first cell goes from 0 to pi/2, the second from pi/2 to pi, the third from pi to 3*np.pi/2, and then there is no cell going to 2*pi.

Comment: Thanks. I added a 5th entry to the phi array of 2pi and that fixed the first problem. I'm still not sure why only two of the three radial bins are showing up though?

Comment: Same reason as for the angles; you have one bin from 0 to 1, and one from 1 to 2.